# parse web page encoded text with scrapy

Tags: parsing, xpath, scrapy

i can't extract the content preview  of book from Online Bookstore
it banned copying previews of books  by encoding the text if i'm not wrong? ,i look for preview of this [book](https://www.neelwafurat.com/itempage.aspx?id=lbb179878-143056&search=books)
from inspect page looks like this, every word is outside the span tag!,the inside span tag ten digit code corresponding to each word

```
<span style='color:red;display:none;'>pq8BMvE37g</span>ولا <span style='color:red;display:none;'>G9XGnpBjnY</span>قدرة
```

i failed after trying  with scrapy python :

```
response.xpath("//*[@class='nabza']").extract()
```

the to filter text

```
response.xpath("//*[@class='nabza']/text()").extract()
```

Comment: do you have question?

Comment: @jsotola  how extract the summary of content of book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way might be to use this XPath :

```
string(//div[@class='nabza'])
```

Then a regex ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) to replace the digit codes with blank spaces.

Alternatively you could use this XPath :

```
//div[@class='nabza']//*[not(self::span)]/text()
```

No more ten digit code. You probably have to make some cleanup (check if the 473 parts of text are correctly merged, check the \r\n,...) and you should obtain something like this :
https://paste2.org/mWhxzxpj

EDIT : R code :

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
page=getURL("https://www.neelwafurat.com/itempage.aspx?id=lbb179878-143056&search=books", httpheader = c('User-Agent' = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"),.encoding = 'UTF-8')
parse=htmlParse(page,encoding = "UTF-8")
text=xpathSApply(parse,"//div[@class='nabza']//*[not(self::span)]/text()",xmlValue)
result=paste0(text,collapse = "")
writeLines(result,"result.txt",useBytes=T)
```

Comment: how negate the regex ? 
response.xpath("//*[@class='nabza']").re ("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
this(?! [a-zA-Z0-9]) didn't work

Comment: My knowledge of Python is very limited (i'm a R user). Why don't you store the result, then use re.sub with the regex to replace with "" ? Alternatively you can try this regex : [\u0621-\u064A]+|[؟:،!."]+ which will select only arabic characters and punctuation. I also have updated my first answer with another approach.

Comment: last question? you 1st approach worked, how did you redirect the ouput to text file as you did?

Comment: I did it in R with writeLines. With Python you could try to export to csv with "Feed Export".

Comment: i spent hours today searchin, no result even with bsoup, how you did it with R if is possible of course